# OpenGL and GLSL on macOS Catalina

Tags: macos, opengl, compiler-errors, glsl, shader

It's quite a few years now that I develop and maintain an OpenGL app on macOS. Even on Catalina it runs beautifully and fast. Now I need to add a **particles** feature and use **glDrawElementsInstancedARB**. The extensions GL_ARB_draw_instanced and GL_ARB_instanced_arrays are present.

As I have read on the web, this command has to be used together with a GLSL shader, so I tried to develop a GLSL shader too. The problem: the shader won't compile. I get an error on the first  line

```
layout (location=0) in vec3 position;
```

also, the max version allowed is

```
#version 130
```

while the GLView app (freely available on the MAS) tells me

```
CORE: OpenGL version 4.1 ATI-3.10.18
COMPATIBILITY: OpenGL version 2.1 ATI-3.10.18
```

and glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION) returns

```
GLSL Version:       1.20
```

I know that Apple has just deprecated OpenGL.
Anyway, do you think is a way to compile my shader?
Should I need to install something extra? If so, should my users install something extra too?

Comment: So what OpenGL version is your context using?

Comment: glGetString(GL_VERSION) returns: 2.1 ATI-3.10.18. And I call it just after [[glView openGLContext] makeCurrentContext];

Comment: But what OpenGL version is associated with the current OpenGL **context**?  The info in your question suggests that it's only OpenGL 2.1/GLSL 1.2 but `glDrawElementsInstanced` requires (I think) OpenGL 3.1.  Please show the code you use to set up/create the context.

Comment: I create an NSOpenGLView and I simply get the context from this view. Then I create a new context with my pixel format this way: NSOpenGLContext *newContext = [[NSOpenGLContext alloc] initWithFormat:pixelFormat shareContext:[self openGLContext]];

Comment: You need to get a newer OpenGL version. On macOS you have to request core profile OpenGL to get newer versions. I suspect you can't do this with NSOpenGLContext.

Comment: How could I request core profile OpenGL to get a newer version ? Anyway, when I see troubles like this one I think it's time to learn Metal and adopt the latest technologies. I just hope that Metal be better and more powerful than OpenGL.

Comment: I think SDL2 is a great framework for getting a GL context (and it can do a lot more too) and it definitely lets you request 3.2+ core profile which gets you a more modern opengl on macOS. But if you only care about macOS then yes you might as well use Metal. It is indeed a lot more powerful than OpenGL on Apple's platforms.

Comment: Thank you Andrea. I think I will go for Metal. Anyway, I'll take a look at the SDL2 too.